# How to make Flexmark-Java process "@"-mentions?

Tags: flexmark

When processing markdown, GitHub supports the `@`-syntax to [mention a username or team](https://help.github.com/articles/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax/#mentioning-people-and-teams). How can such mentions be processed with Flexmark-Java? With following code snippet, `Hello, @world !` is reported as a single `Text` node where I would expect to get `world` reported separately as some kind of *MentionsNode*:

```
final Parser parser = Parser.builder(new Parser.Builder()).build();
final Document document = parser.parse("Hello, @world !");
new NodeVisitor(Collections.emptyList()) {
       public void visit(Node node) {
           System.out.println("Node: " + node);
           super.visit(node);
       }
   }.visit(document);
```

Output:

```
Node: Document{}
Node: Paragraph{}
Node: Text{text=Hello, @world !}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a corresponding extension for this:

```
final MutableDataHolder options = new MutableDataSet()
                .set(Parser.EXTENSIONS, Collections.singletonList(GfmUsersExtension.create()));
final Parser parser = Parser.builder(options).build();
final Document document = parser.parse("Hello, @world, and #1!");
...
```